# Cancelling an Azure Function with a queue trigger without the poison queue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-queues

We're using the following setup:

We're using an Azure Function with a queue trigger to process a queue of JSON messages.

These messages are each just forwarded to an API endpoint via HTTP POST, for further processing.

The API can return 3 possible HTTP status codes; 200 (OK), 400 (Bad Request), 500 (Internal Server Error).

If the API returns 200, the message was processed properly and everything is fine. The queue trigger function appears to automatically delete the queue message and that's fine by us.

If the API returns 400, the API has logic which takes the message and adds it to a table with a status indicating that it was malformed or otherwise couldn't be processed. We are therefore fine with the message being automatically being deleted from the queue and the Azure Function can end normally.

If the API returns 500, we make sure the function retries posting the message to the API, until the status code is 200 or 400 (because there's likely a problem with the API and we don't want lost messages). We're using [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) to achieve this. We have it set up so it's essentially going to keep retrying forever on an exponential backoff.

We recently encountered this problem however:

There are certain situations where the API will return 500 for certain messages. This error is completely transient and will come and go unpredictably. Retrying forever using Polly would be fine except not all messages cause this error and essentially the "bad" messages are blocking "good" messages from being processed.

Let's say for example I have 50 messages in the queue. The first 32 messages at the front of the queue are "bad" and will sometimes return 500 from the API. These messages are picked up by the Azure Function and worked on concurrently. The other 18 messages are "good" and will return 200. These "good" messages will not be processed until the "bad" ones have been successfully processed. Essentially the bad ones cause a traffic jam for the good ones.

My solution was to try to cancel execution of the Azure Function if the current message has been retried a certain number of times. I thought maybe the message would then be made visible after some time, but in that time it gives the good messages time to be processed. However, I have no idea how to cancel execution of the function without either causing the queue message to be completely deleted or pushed onto a poison queue.

Am I able to achieve this using a queue trigger function? Is this something I can maybe do using a timer trigger instead?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you've mentioned, you can't effectively cancel execution, so I'd suggest finishing the function and moving the message to a queue where it will be processed later.

A few suggestions:

- Throw an error to use the poison queue, and handle the logic there.
- Push these messages to another 'long running' queue of your choice, with an output binding.
- Use an output binding of type `CloudQueue` that connects to your input queue. When you encounter a problematic message, add it to the output queue using the `initialVisibilityDelay` parameter to push it to the back of the queue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.addmessage?view=azure-dotnet

---

Edit: [Here's a cheatsheet of parameter binding types](https://jhaleyfiles2016.blob.core.windows.net/public/Azure%20WebJobs%20SDK%20Cheat%20Sheet%202014.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much! So just to clarify, if I throw an error to use the poison queue, I'll still then have to use another function to handle the logic and try sending it again?
Also, the documentation you've linked doesn't show being able to use the output binding of type CloudQueue, just CloudQueueMessage. Am I able to use a CloudQueueMessage and just set the NextVisibleTime or should the documentation be showing I can use a CloudQueue?

Comment: Correct, poison queue would require another function triggering off of the poison queue. I believe that NextVisibleTime is read-only, so you'll need the queue sdk object. Edited the answer with a cheat sheet of types you can bind to parameters

Comment: Excellent, thanks very much, that cheat sheet is very useful! So I just specify the output queue name in the function.json file as an output binding, then add the CloudQueue parameter and the argument will have the value of that queue when the function runs? Am I able to use the same queue as my input queue? I'm thinking that as long as we increase the visibility delay a substantial amount and then add it back into the same queue, it gives the function enough time to process the other messages.

Comment: Yep, exactly. I don't think you can use a CloudQueue as a trigger input - we need to dequeue and take ownership of the message that triggers the function. You can give it a shot though.

Comment: Perfect, I'll add a message to the same queue that the message came from and set a delay so it's at the back of the queue. I'll give this a go and see if there are any further issues.Thanks very much!